# Problem with React component library after updating rollup ( React.jsx: type is invalid ...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup

After updating rollup from `2.70.1` to `3.5.0` my React component library doesn't work anymore. Any library component used from my main project will lead to the error:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at MyLibraryComponent
    at ...
```

and subsequent issues. When I copy this component directly into my main project, it works just fine.

My main project is based on cjs, and so is my component library.

The TypeScript declarations in `@my-react-component-library/dist/index.d.ts` look alright, e.g. like:

```js
declare const MyLibraryComponent: React.FC<Props$a>;
```

, and the `@my-react-component-library/dist/cjs/index.js` like that:

```js
var MyLibraryComponent = function (_a) {
    ...
    return (jsxRuntime.jsx(material.Box, __assign({ style: {...} }, { children: ...) })));
};
```

The `rollup.config.mjs` looks like that:

```js
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve"; //15.0.1 
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs"; //23.0.3
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript"; //10.0.1
import excludeDependenciesFromBundle from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external"; //1.1.23
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss"; //4.0.2
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image"; //3.0.1
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts"; //5.0.0
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy"; //3.4.0

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: 'dist/cjs/index.js',
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: "dist/esm/index.js",
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      excludeDependenciesFromBundle({dependencies:true, peerDependencies:true}),
      resolve({ rootDir: "src" }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      image(),
      postcss(),
      copy({
        targets: [{ src: "public/", dest: "dist/" }]
      })
    ],
    context: "this"
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    external: [/\.css$/],
    plugins: [dts()]
  }
];
```

I'ld be grateful for any ideas what I'm missing!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Been troubleshooting for days. Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: @Cleanshooter Not really. I dropped it and migrated the component library back into the main project.